# How to keep my model data when do GET>POST>REDIRECT to upload a file?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, redirect, asp.net-mvc-5, tempdata

I want to create a register form using MVC which include a **profile photo**. I *don't want to add record* for people *before* completing the form (including profile photo upload). Also I want my UploadImage view and controller to be **re-usable** for many forms (not just this form). I pass three variables to my upload form through `ActionLink`: `RedirectAction (RA)`, `RedirectController (RC)`, and `dataname` and the procedure goes like this:

1. I store `RA, RC, dataname` in `ViewBag`, then  put them in `hidden <input> tags` to be submitted when POSTing the file

   ```
   // GET: UploadImage/Upload
     public ActionResult Upload(string RA, string RC, string dataname)
       {
           ViewBag.RedirectAction = RA;
           ViewBag.RedirectController = RC;
           ViewBag.DataName = dataname;

           return View();
       }
   ```
2. Put these lines in my Upload.cshtml (View):

   ```
   @using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "UploadImage", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
   {
       <input type="file" name="file" />
       <input type="hidden" name="RA" value="@ViewBag.RedirectAction" />
       <input type="hidden" name="RC" value="@ViewBag.RedirectController" />
       <input type="hidden" name="dataname" value="@ViewBag.DataName" />
       <input type="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Upload" />
   }
   ```
3. Store the `filename` in `TempData` with `dataname` as the `Key` and redirect to `/RC/RA`:

   ```
     // POST: UploadImage/Upload/
     [HttpPost]
      public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file, string RA , string RC , string dataname)
       {
            var filepath = "C:/myfilename.jpg";
            TempData.Add(dataname, filepath);
          return RedirectToAction(RA,RC);
       }
   ```
4. And get my filepath by utilizing `TempData` in my register form:

   ```
    @if (TempData.Keys.Contains("MyData")) { 
   <div class="form-group">
       <p>@TempData["MyData"].ToString()</p>
   </div>}
   ```

The code works just fine, but **the essential caveat is that I don't want other completed fields to get lost** when redirected to the register form. How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Bit understand why your doing this, as opposed to just uploading the file with the form - all you doing is degrading performance, and you current `TempData` approach will just fail if the user refreshes the browser anyway. If for some reason you want to upload the file separately before saving the main form, use ajax (in conjunction with `FormData`), or one of the many jquery plugins designed for this, and return the file path which you could store in a hidden input.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to stick the data in the session. Another option would be to use a separate database table to hold in-progress registration data.